# How to Reduce conditions of Piecewise function

Tags: simplifying-expressions

**Edit**

I had problems with pasting an example to stackoverflow itself so here is the link to PasteBin containing sample code: https://pastebin.com/yi6AyrHy

---

I have fairly big piecewise function which I'm willing to gradually simplify. The main issue is piecewise function conditions, which are presented in unreadable form. A call to Reduce[...] simplifies the form, for example:

```
Reduce[w == 1/2 + x && w + x == 0, {x, y}]
```

Which gives:

```
w == 1/4 && x == -(1/4)
```

But the question is how to apply Reduce to every condition of piecewise function?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you seen [PiecewiseExpand](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) and [LogicalExpand](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogicalExpand.html)? Maybe they can help to preprocess your function a bit.

Comment: Hi @Roman I did, but they do not help any much, the expressions remain the same

Comment: Please post what you tried, because problems with code often require the code for the problem to be diagnosed. Here's what I got: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9t71q.png

Comment: I can't stackoverflow rejects the question because it contains too much code...

Comment: @MichaelE2 I've updated the answer, I've put code into PasteBin so feel free to review...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you can try `PiecewiseExpand` with the `Method` suboption `"ConditionSimplifier"` set to `Reduce` as shown in [the first example in PiecewiseExpand >> Options >> Method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html):

```
pw = Min[x^2 + 2 x - 2, Max[2 x^2 - 3 x + 4, x^2 - 3]]
```

> Min[-2 + 2 x + x^2, Max[-3 + x^2, 4 - 3 x + 2 x^2]]

```
 PiecewiseExpand[pw]

 % // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  x^2-3 & x>-\frac{1}{2}\land x^2-3 x\leq -7 \\
>  x^2+2 x-2 & \left(x^2-3 x>-7\land x^2-5 x\geq -6\right)\lor \left(x^2-3 x\leq -7\land x\leq
>    -\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
>  2 x^2-3 x+4 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

```
PiecewiseExpand[pw, Method -> {"ConditionSimplifier" -> Reduce}]

 % // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  x^2+2 x-2 & x\leq 2\lor x\geq 3 \\
>  2 x^2-3 x+4 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

Comment: Wow, it really did work, thank you!