# How to simplify the conditions of a Piecewise function (Maximize output)?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, piecewise, maximize

I'm new on the forum and on Mathematica.  I'm studying the crest of a function of the three variables *c*, *e*, *g3*. With "crest" I mean I'm maximizing the function only over *c*, keeping the dependence on *e* and *g3*.  The output of `Maximize` is a piecewise function with five cases, but the conditions for each case seem very tangled. In particular, I noticed that there are terms as in the image:[image: This is part of the condition of a case.]  It is evident that some condition could be collapsed in fewer parentheses. I'm asking, is there a way to avoid *in advance* this "redundancy"? I already tried to use `PiecewiseExpand` as suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211900/how-to-reduce-conditions-of-piecewise-function) but the running time seems too long (I aborted the run after nearly one hour waiting).
**Edit:** the code I use is the following:

```
Erg3[e_, e1_, c_, g3_] := e - g3*c - e1/2 + Sqrt[e1/4]*Sqrt[e1 - 4*c^2*e1*g3*(1 - g3) - 4*c*g3 (e - c)]  
e1 = 1/Pi  
Erg3red[e_, c_, g3_] = Erg3[e, e1, c, g3]  
sol3 = Maximize[{Erg3red[e, c, g3], e > 0 && e < 1 && c >= Max[0, (e - e1)/(1 - e1)] && c <= e && 0 < g3 < 1 && 0 <= e1 <= 1}, c]  
(*then I tried*)
pwe = PiecewiseExpand[sol3[[1]],Method -> {"ConditionSimplifier" -> Reduce}]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load Mathematica code that can be copied/pasted/executed in our own notebook sessions. Thanks.